# Generating XACML advice string dynamically in a policy or rule

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3, abac

Is there a way to generate the `Advice` or `Obligation` string returned in the XACML response dynamically dependent on the attributes used in the evaluation(e.g. environment)?

For example, through an extension which implements the logic.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The idea is to generate a specific advice dependant of the user without having to define rules for everyone. Not sure if this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XACML 3.0, `Obligation` and `Advice` elements can contain attribute assignments. Attribute assignments are placeholders that can be filled in with a static value or a dynamic value e.g. a value that comes from another XACML attribute. For instance, we could have the following (using [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa) notation - the [Axiomatics Language for Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML))):

```
obligation notifyManager = "com.axiomatics.examples.notification.notifyManager"
policy accessDocs{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule denyOutOfOffice{
        target clause currentTime>"17:00:00":time or currentTime<"09:00:00":time
        deny
        on deny{
            obligation notifyManager{
                com.axiomatics.examples.message = "You cannot access anything outside office hours"
                com.axiomatics.examples.user.managerEmail = com.axiomatics.examples.user.managerEmail
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

In this example, the obligation has 2 placeholders:

- com.axiomatics.examples.message: this placeholder contains a static value.
- com.axiomatics.examples.user.managerEmail: this placeholder contains a dynamic value.

You can use functions in placeholders e.g. string concatenation.

The XACML source looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). 
 Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/example.accessDocs"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    Version="1.0">
    <xacml3:Description />
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target />
    <xacml3:Rule 
            Effect="Deny"
            RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/example.accessDocs.denyOutOfOffice">
        <xacml3:Description />
        <xacml3:Target>
            <xacml3:AnyOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-less-than">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">17:00:00</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                            AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment"
                            MustBePresent="false"
                        />
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
                <xacml3:AllOf>
                    <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-greater-than">
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">09:00:00</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                            AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment"
                            MustBePresent="false"
                        />
                    </xacml3:Match>
                </xacml3:AllOf>
            </xacml3:AnyOf>
        </xacml3:Target>
        <xacml3:ObligationExpressions>
            <xacml3:ObligationExpression ObligationId="com.axiomatics.examples.notification.notifyManager"
            FulfillOn="Deny">
                <xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.message" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">
                    <xacml3:AttributeValue
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">You cannot access anything outside office hours</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                </xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression>
                <xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.user.manager.email" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
                    <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                        AttributeId="com.axiomatics.examples.user.manager.email"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"
                        MustBePresent="false"
                    />
                </xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression>
            </xacml3:ObligationExpression>
        </xacml3:ObligationExpressions>
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```

Comment: In this example, if i have a logic like "if no manager, email to HR", is that something i should put into an XACML policy? or is that application logic?

Comment: If it's about access (which in this case it is) then yes it belongs to the policy